Understanding very high StartBundle and FinishBundle wall times compared to ProcessElement
While investigating high system latency in a Python Apache Beam pipeline running on Dataflow, I noticed that for some steps the reported StartBundle and/or FinishBundle wall times can totally dominate the ProcessElement time.
At first glance that doesn't seem very healthy to me, and I'm wondering if it indicates some deeper issue.
Examples of processing in these steps:

Reading bytes from Kafka and parsing them with FastAvro
Stateful DoFn with cache and timer




Hi @Gergely, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support Case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue trackerdescribing your issue

Thanks! In the meantime we opened a support ticket and I'll also try to work on a minimalistic repro case.
